# Can I put a Button to bottom of a ConstraintLayout inside ScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ScrollView` contains a `ConstraintLayout`. Inside the `ConstraintLayout`, I put many views with an attribute `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` to make a relation between the view and the view top of it, and I used `layout_marginTop` to put spaces between the views.

In my design, I have a Button that should be in the bottom of the layout and it cannot happen with the `layout_marginTop` because it should have a relation with the bottom of the `ConstraintLayout`.

Here's my code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="120dp"
            android:text="Logo"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/un_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="User name"
            android:textColor="#bebebe"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pw_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="#bebebe"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/un_et" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/save_pw"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="28dp"
            android:paddingRight="28dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pw_et">

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:buttonTint="#bebebe"
                android:text="Save account"
                android:textColor="#bebebe" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Forget password?"
                android:textColor="#a40000" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/save_pw" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Sign up"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did my question help? If it did, highlight it is as the question.

Comment: Are the views in the ConstraintLayout dynamic? I mean can the number of views change over time as the app is used? If so, then you should check out RecyclerView because it is designed for this situation.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Exactly, what I was wondering because that would imply using RecyclerView

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it's not dynamic, it's just a login activity

Comment: @GauravMall yeah, thanks

Comment: Then select it as the answer!

Comment: @AbdurrahmanAnas If Gaurav's answer still doesn't solve your problem, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @Code-Apprentice done, check it

Answer (score 10):

Replace `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView` & also add `android:fillViewport="true"` like this

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

            // rest of code

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Sign up"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn" 
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: You can use `fillViewport` on a regular `ScrollView`.

Comment: Yup, and ConstraintLayout can have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 5):

Just set this property to your button:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Then add this to your last view this property:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
```

Also, add to your last view:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="height_of_button"
```

However, if you are adding a lot of views it would be better to populate them inside a **RecyclerView** using an Adapter. Decide what you want to do. Also, tell me if I understood your question correctly, it was a bit confusing.

Comment: why did you use "width_of_button"? it's="match_parent" in my project

Comment: It's just a placeholder. You can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: In your case `match_parent`

Comment: there is an error when i try to do this: [android:layout_marginBottom="match_parent"] , you can check my code above i added it

Comment: margin bottom shouldn't be match parent. It should be the height of your button. I'm sorry I labeled it as width

Answer (score 2):

I found one solution to keep the button at the bottom, doesn't matter is your text is dynamic, read about `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias` https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#Bias

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_gallery"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:isScrollContainer="true">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/texto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text=" Text \n Text" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Buton1"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/texto"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```